# Pandas DF and RE - Find a match Y. Then find the last occurence of X

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have data that looks like this:

```
    /media/info/DRIVE/Animal/Stuff
    Rights: _RWCEMF_     User / Group .CN=Dog.OU=Random.OU=Place.O=X.T=X.
    Rights: _RWCEMF_     User / Group .CN=Cat.OU=Random.OU=Place.O=X.T=X.
    /media/info/DRIVE/Tricks/Treats
    Rights: _RWCEMF_     User / Group .CN=Gorilla.OU=Random.OU=Place.O=X.T=X.
    Rights: _RWCEMF_     User / Group .CN=Hippo.OU=Random.OU=Place.O=X.T=X.
    Rights: _R______     User / Group .CN=Dog.OU=Random.OU=Place.O=X.T=X.
    /media/info/DRIVE/Private/Hideout
    Rights: _RWCEMF_     User / Group .CN=Hippo.OU=Random.OU=Place.O=X.T=X.
```

Say this goes on for thousands of lines, I would like to see all of the permissions that Dog has.  Ideally the output would look something like this:

```
    /DRIVE/Animal/Stuff   Rights: _RWCEMF_
    /DRIVE/Tricks/Treats  Rights: _R______
```

Question: Is this something I should be tackling with a Regular Expression?  I've been doing some reading/trials and it appears you cannot find **Dog** and then lookback for the most recent occurrence of **/media/info/DRIVE** because lookback checks a static amount of characters.

On the other hand, lookahead finds the first match and then continues to look for the 2nd match- even if that's hundreds of lines later in a totally separate drive.

Any ideas on how to approach this?  I'm spinning my wheels with this one.  All searches point to Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd

data = []
for line in open('temp.text'):
    if line.startswith('/media/'):
        path = line[:-1]
    else:
        rights = line.split()[1]
        owner = re.match('.*.CN=([^.]+).*', line).groups()[0]
        row = {'path': path, 'right': rights, 'owner': owner}
        data.append(row)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df.owner=='Dog']
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  I was way overthinking this- in fact this is better because I can keep referencing the df to get permissions of other users without going through the whole process again.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch the first 8 characters of the strings obtained using this regex:

```
_.*Dog
```

This will give you all the strings that start with the permissions of Dog.

Or if _ is not a precondition, you can look for the substring (2-9) of the strings obtained in this way:

```
:.*Dog
```